# Drawer Menu - Submenu on Side

Tags: flutter

i try to find a solution for the flutter drawer menu. i implement the normal drawer and the menu looks find. now i want to draw a submenu for many items.

i found this [Flutter how to add a Expandable menu item inside navigation drawer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51706739/flutter-how-to-add-a-expandable-menu-item-inside-navigation-drawer) but this is not what i want. this show the subitems under the header item. i want a solution to click on the headitem and a new page slide in the drawer with a new list of subitems and the headelement is in top to go back to the mainmenu. here is a example what i mean.

[image: example]

i hope anyone can help.

Comment: That's is not a recommended UX at all. The Drawer, following the Android logic, should switch between Fragments (Pages) in the same level/layer... once you tap into an item it changes the Fragment/Page. If the item is a settings, it will open an inner page (new Activity following the Android logic) and you need the arrow back to return.

Comment: other meanings ?

Comment: I'm not following you... other meanings? There's no implementation on any app (from Google or Apple) using that kind of UI/UX and may be rejected by the Stores for not following their guidelines.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a nested Navigator inside the Drawer widget and control the menu navigation with a Key.

See the example on DartPad: https://dartpad.dev/?id=250b450f0c59b1cda6add362e7d6f7c4

```dart
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Drawer with Navigator',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MainScreen(),
    );
  }
}

final _navigatorKey = GlobalKey();

class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('My page'),
      ),
      drawer: Drawer(
        child: Navigator(
          key: _navigatorKey, // Sets the navigator key
          initialRoute: '/',
          onGenerateRoute: (routeSettings) {
            if (routeSettings.name == '/') {
              // Render initial drawer content
              return MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => ListView(
                  children: [
                    const UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
                      accountEmail: Text("jd@mail.com"),
                      accountName: Text("John Doe"),
                      currentAccountPicture: CircleAvatar(
                        child: Text("JD"),
                      ),
                    ),
                    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                      SubMenuItem(path: '${i + 1}'),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }
            return null;
          },
        ),
      ),
      body: const Center(child: Text('Main page content')),
    );
  }
}

class SubMenu extends StatelessWidget {
  final String path;

  const SubMenu({super.key, required this.path});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Menu $path')),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          for (var i = 0; i <= Random().nextInt(5); i++)
            SubMenuItem(path: '$path.${i + 1}'),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SubMenuItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final String path;

  const SubMenuItem({super.key, required this.path});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      title: Text('Go to menu $path'),
      trailing: const Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_right),
      onTap: () {
        // Pushing a page in the nested navigation
        Navigator.of(_navigatorKey.currentContext!).push(
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => SubMenu(path: path),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented something like what you wanted. Used a method called buildMainmenu() that takes the list of menu items as the parameter. isSublist variable is taken to differentiate between main menu and the sub menu. Using setState() method to update the contents of the drawer. Attached code might help you!

```
import 'package:webview/core/models/Menu.dart';
import 'package:webview/viewmodel/web_view_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:xml_parser/xml_parser.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:logcat/logcat.dart';


class NestedDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
  final WebViewModel model;

  CustomDrawer(this.model);

  @override
  _NestedDrawerState createState() => _NestedDrawerState();
}

class _NestedDrawerState extends State<NestedDrawer> {
  bool isSublist = false;
  List<Menu> subList = List();
  String subMenuTitle = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Drawer(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(

                width: double.maxFinite,
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
                child:  Stack(children: <Widget>[
                  Visibility(
                    visible: isSublist,
                    maintainSize: true,
                    maintainAnimation: true,
                    maintainState: true,
                    child:  Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,

                        child: InkWell(
                          child: Icon(
                            Icons.arrow_back_ios,
                              color: Colors.green
                          ),
                          onTap: () {
                            backToMainMenu();
                          },
                        )),
                  ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text(
                      !isSublist?
                      "Main menu" : subMenuTitle,

                    ),
                  )
                ])

            ),
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0,0),),
            !isSublist
                ? Expanded(
              // Main menu
              flex: 2,
              child: buildMainmenu(widget.model.itemsList),
            )
                : Expanded(
              // Sub menu
                flex: 2,
                child: buildMainmenu(subList))
          ],
        ));
  }

  Widget buildMainmenu(List<Menu> menus) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: menus.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              menus[index].subMenuList.length == 0
                  ? InkWell(
                child: Row(children: <Widget>[
                  menus[index].iconUrl != null
                      ? Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 0, 0),
                      child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                        placeholder:
                        "assets/${menus[index].iconPath}",
                        image: menus[index].iconUrl,
                        height: 20,
                        width: 20,
                      ))
                      : Container(),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 0, 0),
                    child: Text(
                      menus[index].label.toString(),
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: double.parse(
                              widget.model.configItems.MenuItemsFontSize),
                          color:
                          widget.model.configItems.MenuItemsFontColor,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    ),
                  )
                ]),
                onTap: (){

                },
              )
                  : InkWell(
                child: Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    menus[index].iconUrl != null
                        ? Align(
                        alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                        child: Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 0, 0),
                            child: FadeInImage.assetNetwork(
                              placeholder:
                              "assets/${menus[index].iconPath}",
                              image: menus[index].iconUrl,
                              height: 20,
                              width: 20,
                            )))
                        : Container(),
                    Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(40, 8, 0, 0),
                        child: Text(
                          menus[index].label.toString(),

                        )),
                    Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 5, 5, 0),
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                          child: Image.asset(
                            'assets/menu/right.png',

                            scale: 4,
                          ),
                        ))
                  ],
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  loadSublistmenu(menus[index].subMenuList,
                      menus[index].label.toString());
                },
              ),
              Divider(color: widget.model.configItems.MenuItemsSeperatorColor),
            ],
          );
        });
  }

  void loadSublistmenu(List<Menu> subMenuList, String title) {
    setState(() {
      subList = subMenuList;
      isSublist = true;
      subMenuTitle = title;
    });
  }

  void backToMainMenu() {
    setState(() {
      isSublist = false;
    });
  }
}
```