# flutter: dropdown in listTile drawer

Tags: flutter

is there a way to implement drawer listTile with dropdown pages like image below?
thanks in advance
[image]

```html
 drawer: Drawer(
          child: ListView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            children: <Widget>[
              DrawerHeader(
                child:  Text('project1',                
              ),
              ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.home),
                title: Text('Home'),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => MyHomePage(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
              
                  );
                },
              ),
```

Comment: you can use ```ExpansionTIle``` than ```ListTile``` .Check this https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-expansion-collapse-view-fde9c51ac438

Comment: i think ExpansionTile  not the one cuz i need to tap on also :/

Comment: You can check the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51706739/flutter-how-to-add-a-expandable-menu-item-inside-navigation-drawer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ExpansionTile](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionTile-class.html) in your Drawer to achieve what you'd like in the screenshot you shared.

```dart
Drawer(
  child: ListView(
    padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
    children: <Widget>[
      DrawerHeader(
        child:  Text('project1',                
      ),
      const ExpansionTile(
        title: Text('Chapter A'),
        children: <Widget>[
          // Add widgets to be shown when expanded
          ListTile(title: Text('This is tile number 1')),
        ],
      ),
      const ExpansionTile(
        title: Text('Chapter B'),
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(title: Text('This is tile number 1')),
        ],
      ),
      const ExpansionTile(
        title: Text('Chapter C'),
        children: <Widget>[
          ListTile(title: Text('This is tile number 1')),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

However, if you really like a dropdown to be added. Then just use [DropdownButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html). The dropdown icon can be customized to fit your use case.